# try except not running except part

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a short code that ftps a small file into a server.

```
session = ftplib.FTP("192.168.0.164", "admin", "admin")
file = open("path/test.txt", "rb")
try:
    session.storbinary("STOR application/test.txt", file)
except:
    print("failed")
else:
    print("success!")
file.close()
```

In the above piece I changed the IP address to so it would fail (there is no 192.168.0.164 device) and it doesn't print failed like it's supposed to.  In the terminal I get a
"connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond" error.

if I mistype the path, I also don't get a failed print on the terminal.

If I type in the correct IP the success part does work.

Am I using the try/except wrong?

UPDATE:

Current code looks like this:

```
file = open("path/test.txt", "rb")
try:
    session = ftplib.FTP("192.168.0.161", "admin", "admin")
    session.storbinary("STOR application/test.txt", file)
except:
     print("Unable to reach host")
else:
    print("success!")
    session.quit()
finally:
    print ("DONE!!")
    file.close()
```

I figure the ftplib.all_errors will catch all errors (host unreachable, and file not found).  It seems to catch the unable to reach host errors, but no file not found errors.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I using the `try/except` wrong?

Your syntax is correct, but Python is not actually reaching the `try` block at all.

When you call `session = ftplib.FTP(host, ...)` where `host` is unreachable, the code will stop in its tracks there. That's because `FTP.__init__()` greedily calls [`self.connect()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5d28bb699a305135a220a97ac52e90d9344a3004/Lib/ftplib.py#L121). This will in turn call `socket.create_connection()`, which will not succeed for an unreachable host.

So, you'd need to modify to:

```
with open("path/test.txt", "rb") as file:
    try:
        session = ftplib.FTP("192.168.0.164", "admin", "admin")
        session.storbinary("STOR application/test.txt", file)
    except Exception as e:
        print("failed")
        print(e)
    else:
        print("success!")
    finally:
        session.quit()
```

Comment: Hi.  I tried your piece and it does work if host is unreachable.  But let's say the path is incorrect (or file cannot be found)  Now I have python failing out saying No such file or directory (instead of running the except.)     Also, do I have to have "quit" my sesssion with session.quit() after file.close()?

Comment: Should wrap it all in a `with` block. That's the python way to deal with file operations. About the file error, you'd still need an `except FileNotFoundError` to deal with it appropriately.

Comment: And yes, you should use `session.quit()`. If you can guarantee that this code will only raise exception in the first line in `try` block, you can `quit()` the session in the `else` block. Otherwise you could have an exception that is raised after the session is defined, but the `session.quit()` would not be called since it's part of the `else` block. In those cases, a `finally` block might come in handy.

Comment: Thanks!  Excuse the noob question, but how do I "wrap it all" in a with block?  I already have an except Exception as e:, I should but a second except block with except FileNotFoundError?